# If a composition of two maps is smooth, as well as one of the maps, then so is the other.

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, smooth-manifolds, function-and-relation-composition

Let $M$, $N$, and $K$ be smooth manifolds, and consider the maps $g:M\to N$, and $f:N\to L$. Assume that the composition $f\circ g$ is smooth.

If any of $f$ and $g$ is smooth can we conclude that the other is also smooth? In particular, is $f$ smooth if $g$ is a smooth surjection? Is any of the preceding statements a case of a categorical theorem? What conditions should $f$ and $g$ satisfy for the first statement to hold true? What conditions should $f$ and $g$ satisfy for the second statement to be true?

Comment: At minimum $g$ must be surjective: for example, we could take $M = \emptyset$, then $g$ and $f \circ g$ are vacuously smooth but $f$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: If one of $f,g$ is constant then the other can be arbitrary

Comment: If all three manifolds are the real line, $f(x) = x^{3} - x$, and $g$ is the Dirichlet function, then $f$ is polynomial and surjective, $f \circ g \equiv 0$ is constant, and $g$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, @ZhenLin. How can we proceed if all maps are surjective?

Comment: There's a partial answer given by the "Lemma" in my answer on this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281848/if-a-subset-admits-a-smooth-structure-which-makes-it-into-a-submanifold-then-it/1281869#1281869

Answer (score 3):

No.

Consider for surjective smooth $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the projection onto the first factor ($(x,y)\rightarrow x$) and, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = (x,1)$ if $x<0$ and $= (x, -1)$ if $x\ge 0$. Then $g$ is not even continuous, but $f \circ g(x) = x$.

(Edit: you can easily modify $g$ from the above example in an obvious fashion so that it is not even continous at any given point and all other statements remain valid).